# Set timeout for a session at user login and logout user at the end of session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-security, session-timeout

I try to make a mechanism in `Spring` that when the user login on the website, I assign for his login session a time of validity. For example, I want to set the session to be active for just 10 minutes and after 10 minutes of inactivity I want to logout the user.

My first implementation is like that:

```
@Service
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60*10); // active session for 10 minutes
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

But doesn't work expected.

So, I tried another way like that:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60*10); // active session for 10 minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().invalidate();
    }
}
```

Here, I noticed the event entry in `sessionDestroyed` function, but `invalidate` function doesn't work as I would expect, so the user can still navigate on the website.

Have everyone any idea about what is my wrong in my configuration or how I can resolve preferably without add config in `web.xml`. I saw many responses with add `session-timeout` in `web.xml`, but I want to make this configuration from Spring configuration classes. And of course, I'm newbie with `Spring` and `Spring Security`.

Comment: Yes it works but your `invalidate` doesn't make sense as that actually triggers the session destroyed listener. Also how are your users doing a login are you using basic authentication by any change? Also timeout will occur after ~ 10minutes (generally the thread that cleans up the sessions runs every minute, so generally it will take a bit longer then 10 minutes for the actual timeout to happen).

Comment: I use basic authentication. What you recommend me to do in this situation? How I can rewrite the logic?

Comment: When using default basic authentication from the browser (and not a JS framework) the browser will send the `Authentication` header on each request. So if there is no session you basically automatically re-authenticate.